# Help on subsetting a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am using %in% for subsetting and I came across a strange result.

```
> my.data[my.data$V3 %in% seq(200,210,.01),]
        V1     V2        V3         V4       V5      V6         V7
56     470   48.7    209.73        yes     26.3      54        470
```

That was correct. But when I widen the range... row 56 just disappears

```
> my.data[my.data$V3 %in% seq(150,210,.01),]
        V1     V2        V3         V4       V5      V6         V7
51     458   48.7    156.19        yes     28.2      58        458
67     511   30.5    150.54        yes     26.1      86        511
73     535   40.6    178.76        yes     29.5      73        535
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?
Is there a better way to subset the dataframe?

Here is its structure

```
> str(my.data)
'data.frame':   91 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 91 levels "100","10004",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ V2: num  44.6 22.3 30.4 38.6 15.2 18.3 16.3 12.2 36.7 12.2 ...
 $ V3: num  110.83 25.03 17.17 57.23 2.18 ...
 $ V4: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V5: num  22.3 30.5 24.4 25.5 4.1 28.4 7.9 5.1 24 12.2 ...
 $ V6: int  50 137 80 66 27 155 48 42 65 100 ...
 $ V7: chr  "" "10004" "10005" "10012" ...
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you are trying to return all rows where `V3` is in a stated range or if you want to return only rows that are equal to the the sequence numbers you intended to be returned?

Comment: Given that V3 is rounded to 2 decimal digits, I thought that "all rows where V3 is in a stated range" is identical to "rows that are equal to a sequence of numbers with an increment of .01". To answer your question, I want the first

Comment: `V3` might be exact, I don't know all the values. The issue is that `seq()`'s values are not rounded, exact and that is the problem. Anyway, doing things by testing for exact equality is destined to fail on a computer using floating point arithmetic. It is far safer/easier/correct to use less than and greater than operators in R. See my Answer or the second option of the Answer by @nullglob (though ignore his first option as that is wrong).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ooops. You are trying to do exact matching on a computer that can't represent all numbers exactly.

```
> any(209.73 == seq(200,210,.01))
[1] TRUE
> any(209.73 == seq(150,210,.01))
[1] FALSE
> any(209.73 == zapsmall(seq(150,210,.01)))
[1] TRUE
```

The reason for the discrepancy is in the second sequence, the value in the sequence is *not* exactly `209.73`. This is something you have to appreciate when doing computation with computers.

This is covered in many places on the interweb, but in relation to R, see [point 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) in the R FAQ.

Anyway, that said, you are going about the problem incorrectly. You want to use proper numeric operators:

```
my.data[my.data$V3 >= 150 & my.data$V3 <= 210, ]
## or
subset(my.data, V3 >= 150 & V3 <= 210)
```